# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression changed error but code works

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, runtime-error

I am getting the following error listed below. I did some research and people said to put it in the ngoninit or ngAfterViewInit but that didnt work so can someone please help me on how i can fix this. The relevent code is listed below.

```
TrialBalanceComponent.html:29 ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'undefined: 374208'. Current value: 'undefined: 748416'.
    at viewDebugError (core.js:7393)
    at expressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError (core.js:7381)
    at checkBindingNoChanges (core.js:7483)
    at checkNoChangesNodeInline (core.js:10346)
    at checkNoChangesNode (core.js:10333)
    at debugCheckNoChangesNode (core.js:10936)
    at debugCheckRenderNodeFn (core.js:10890)
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (TrialBalanceComponent.html:29)
    at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.js:10879)
    at checkNoChangesView (core.js:10234)
```

Html code:

```
<td>{{totalDebits() | number:'1.2'}}</td>
<td>{{totalcredits() | number:'1.2'}}</td>
```

ts code:

```
totalDebits() {
    let totalDebit = 0;
    this.accountList.forEach((account) => {
      if (account.accountType === 'debit') {
        this.totalDebitBalance.push(account.accountBalance);
      }
    });

    this.totalDebitBalance.forEach((amount) => {
      totalDebit = totalDebit + amount;
    });

    return totalDebit;
}

  totalcredits() {
    let totalCredit = 0;
    this.accountList.forEach((account) => {
      if (account.accountType !== 'credit') {
        this.totalCreditBalance.push(account.accountBalance);
      }
    });

    this.totalCreditBalance.forEach((amount) => {
      totalCredit = totalCredit + amount;
    });

    return totalCredit;
  }
```

below is me putting the code in ng on init but then i get a value of 0 from the html call.

```
<td><b>${{totalDebitAmount | number:'1.2'}} </b></td>
<td><b>${{totalCreditAmount | number:'1.2'}}</b></td>
```

ts code

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.totalDebits();
    this.totalcredits();
  }

  totalDebits() {
    let totalDebit = 0;
    this.accountList.forEach((account) => {
      if (account.accountType === 'debit') {
        this.totalDebitBalance.push(account.accountBalance);
      }
    });

    this.totalDebitBalance.forEach((amount) => {
      totalDebit = totalDebit + amount;
    });
    this.totalDebitAmount = totalDebit;
    // return totalDebit;
}

  totalcredits() {
    let totalCredit = 0;
    this.accountList.forEach((account) => {
      if (account.accountType !== 'credit') {
        this.totalCreditBalance.push(account.accountBalance);
      }
    });

    this.totalCreditBalance.forEach((amount) => {
      totalCredit = totalCredit + amount;
    });

    this.totalCreditAmount = totalCredit;
    // return totalCredit;
  }
```

Comment: Putting in the NgOnInit or NgAfterInit is 100% correct, and your current code shows neither???

Comment: @AustinTFrench i added it to the NgOnInit and posted the code above but this removes the error but the values of totalDebitAmount and totalCreditAmount as 0 whereas if i leave it with the error i get the right value

Comment: This error can have several causes, and there are a few workarounds: https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4 For me, manually checking for changes using `changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();` has worked well without any noticeable performance impacts.

Comment: `ngAfterContentChecked()` is a good point in the component lifecycle to perform the check.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently removing the totalCreditBalance list push and the totalCreditBalance list fixed the problem.